# Explaining Example of Euler-Lagrange Equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

It seems quite clear to me that for a function $y=f(x)$, $\frac{d(y')}{dy}=\frac{d(y')}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}$. [This exploration of the Euler Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Examples) claims that, for $F(x,y,y')=\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$, we find $$\frac{d}{dy}F(x,y,y')=0$$However, it seems to me that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}F(x,y,y')&=\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}\Big{(}\frac{d}{dy}(1+(y')^2)\Big{)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}\Big{(}2y'\frac{d(y')}{dy}\Big{)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}\Big{(}2y'\frac{y''(x)}{y'(x)}\Big{)}\\
&=\frac{2y''(x)}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}\neq{0}
\end{align}
$$
What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the (convenient but awful) notation that is used in the calculus of variations.

The $y,y'$ in the expression are (from the point of view of the expression)
unrelated.

Write $F(a,b,c) = \sqrt{1+c^2}$, then ${\partial F(a,b,c) \over \partial b} = 0$.

Comment: The context of the question seems to strongly imply that y and y' are related though, as the differential equation is then solved for y. What if f had been some function of both y and y'?

Comment: $y,y',y'',...$ are related of course. But when the expression $F(x,y,y')$ is differentiated, it is with to respect to the first, second, etc, variables. That is why my comment regarding 'awful'!

Comment: The notation trips many people up.